# Sumproduct in C

Tags: c

Not sure what the technical term for this is but I'm trying to multiply two arrays of equal size in C. I want it to act like sumproduct in Excel; multiply each number in a position and sum them.

What I want:

`correctResult = [0] * [0] + [1] * [1] + [2] * [2]`

What I don't want is the result that two foor loops give which is:

`incorrectResult = [0] * [0] + [0] *[1] + [0] * [2] + ... + [2] * [1] + [2] * [2]`

Is this possible with loops? I have a problem with multiple two 2D arrays but I would assume the same concept applies to 1D or 2D.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? <br/>
This is indeed possible in ```C```, you just have to create a new array, loop on both input arrays and do your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

For 1D Array , solution would be like this :

Suppose two arrays are A & B of equal size n

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    result = result + A[i]*B[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but why not just use a single for loop? This problem is not really specific to C but if you're specifically having problems with language here's a sample snippet:

```
int dot_product(int const *arr1, int const *arr2, size_t len) {
    int ret = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        ret += arr1[i] * arr2[i];
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Clear and simple. It might be better to use type `double` for the arrays and return value.